# Integer solutions for $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2 - 3b^2 = 2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Just out of curiosity, how do I find  integer solutions for $a$ and $b$ such that $$a^2 - 3b^2 = 2?$$

Comment: Hint:  try solving the "easier" equation $a^2-3c=2$....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has none.

$$a^2\equiv 2\pmod 3$$

Impossible, because quadratic residues $\pmod 3$ are $0,1$ only.

Or you can try writing $a=3m$ or $a=3m\pm 1$ and see that $a^2$ leaves remainders $0$ or $1$ when divided by $3$, no matter what number $a$ is.

Comment: That's nice, thanks!

Comment: The trick of writing $a = 3m$ is actually ingenious.

Answer (score 0):

Before solving an equation, or a system of equations, make sure to count the number of variables **varying** and the number of equations you have.

In your case, you have :

- 2 variables varying
- 1 equation

How will you be able to find a relation between b and a in this case? You'll end up with either :

- No solutions
- An infinite number of solutions

In your case, given a and b $ \in $ $\mathbb{N}$, it has no solution because if you fix for example a, you have b $\notin$ $\mathbb{N}$. Check WolframAlpha for futher information.

This kind of equation belongs to non linear diophantine equation, maybe you should check it. Best of luck.

Comment: What is your proof that if you fix $a$, you have $b\not\in\mathbb N$? How do you know that the equation has either zero or an infinite amount of solutions? Remember that it's not an equation in real variables but in integers.